# Secure AES encryption and decryption in Android

Tags: java, security, android, aes

Is this implementation of AES for Android safe? Is it 128 bit encryption? How can I strengthen this implementation? Please help me, all suggestions are welcome :)

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESEncryption {

    private static final String SecretKey = "9081726354fabced";
    private static final String Salt = "03xy9z52twq8r4s1uv67";
    private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private static final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String SECRET_KEY_ALGORITHM = "PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC";
    private static final String RANDOM_ALGORITHM = "SHA-512";
    private static final int PBE_ITERATION_COUNT = 100;
    private static final int PBE_KEY_LENGTH = 256;
    private static final int IV_LENGTH = 16;
    private Cipher cipher;

    public AESEncryption() {
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            cipher = null;
        }
        catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            cipher = null;
        }
        randomInt = new Random();
    }

    public SecretKey getSecretKey(String password) {
            try {
                PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), Salt.getBytes("UTF-8"), PBE_ITERATION_COUNT, PBE_KEY_LENGTH);
                SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SECRET_KEY_ALGORITHM);
                SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
                SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), KEY_ALGORITHM);
                return secret;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
    }

    public String encrypt(String text) {
        Thread.sleep(randomInt.nextInt(100));
        if (text == null || text.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        byte[] encrypted = null;
        try {
            byte[] iv = generateIV();
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(SecretKey), ivspec);
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {                       
            return null;
        }
        return Base64.encodeToString(iv, Base64.DEFAULT)+Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    public String decrypt(String code) {
        Thread.sleep(randomInt.nextInt(100));
        if(code == null || code.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        byte[] decrypted = null;
        try {
            String iv64 = code.substring(0, IV_LENGTH*2);
            String encrypted64 = code.substring(IV_LENGTH*2);
            byte[] iv = Base64.decode(iv64, Base64.DEFAULT);
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(SecretKey), ivspec);
            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(encrypted64, Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
    }

    private byte[] generateIV() {
        try {
            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance(RANDOM_ALGORITHM);
            byte[] iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH];
            random.nextBytes(iv);
            return iv;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /*public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data) {
        String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        if (data == null) {
            return null;
        }
        final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(2*data.length);
        for (final byte b : data) {
            hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4)).append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
        }
        return hex.toString();
    }*/


    /*public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else if (str.length() < 2) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            int len = str.length()/2;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
    }*/

}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

**Edit:** The code throws an exception because Android can't find "PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC". This is when I run the code on my phone, at least. What algorithm can I take now to replace this unknown one? The algorithm for SecretKeyFactory must be compatible to AES and the key size, right?

Comment: Hi pal, not to sound like a bad sport, but does this class come with any license restriction to it? You don't specify in the headers and i would like to know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I observe the following deficiencies:

- Use of strings to store the key, which is then extracted using `getBytes()`. This has multiple problems:

  - The character encoding used to convert the string to bytes can vary between Java implementations (so while the Android spec forces UTF-8 to be the default character encoding, your code won't be portable to J2SE, even though it will compile - dangerous). `String.getBytes()` should be deprecated if it isn't already; you should always supply an argument specifying the character encoding to use (and 99% of the time it should be `"UTF-8"`).
  - Certain character encodings (including UTF-8) place additional constraints on the valid values of bytes which mean that you lose some of the keyspace. It would be better to base-64 encode it (and use `android.util.Base64` to decode) or hex-encode it (using the static methods which you've posted - although see below).
- Bad padding. If you look at that code carefully you'll see that it pads with spaces on encryption and doesn't unpad on decryption. So you'll have to unpad in the next layer up, and if the encrypted string ends in one or more spaces you'll unpad incorrectly. I would remove `padString` and the call to it, and change the cipher algorithm to `AES/CBC/PKCS7` (assuming that it's supported; if not, try `AES/CBC/PKCS5`).
- Reuse of IV. In certain applications this is excusable, but as a general rule you should use a different, randomly generated, IV for each message and send it (unencrypted) along with the message. Otherwise if your messages start out with the same text then an eavesdropper can get information on where they diverge.
- Whoever wrote `bytesToHex` is probably more experienced with PHP than Java, because otherwise they would know that building a string in a loop like that is inexcusable for someone who's been programming Java for more than two weeks. Given that the size of the output is known from the start, I'd be inclined to just build it into a `char[]` and then call the `String(char[])` constructor rather than use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter! I tried to implement all your suggestions (except for the IV reuse, which I want to retain). Did I succeed? The class should be more secure now, isn't it?

Comment: @MarcoW., is there a reason for using PBE rather than generating a key with full entropy and hex-coding it? Also, I didn't pay enough attention to the asymmetry between encode and decode. Probably both `encrypt` and `decrypt` should take strings and return strings.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed both methods to return strings. But concerning PBE, I thought this would be a safe way of retrieving a 256 bit key. Is it not? I need the fixed-length key.

Comment: @MarcoW., it's not bad per se, but it's a bit overkill if you're hard-coding the key. What do you mean by "fixed-length"?

Comment: So you could call the class safe now? Is this a secure implementation if ignore the hard-coded key, salt and IV? What I wanted to say is that you need a key with 256 bit length. Right? So I can't take a string such as "my_secure_key7" as the key.

Comment: @MarcoW., depends on your threat model - there may still be timing attacks - but it at least avoids some of the simpler errors. You could take a random 64-character hex string as the key.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me so much! My last two questions: Can I prevent timing attacks by adding a sleep() with a short random sleep time in the encryption and decryption functions? And, if you see my edit in the question: Does this way of implementing IV enhance security? The IV is now randomly generated on encryption and then added to the beginning of the result string. On deryption, the IV is extracted from the beginning of the encrypted text and used for decryption.

Comment: @MarcoW., random sleep could help, yes, although it depends on whether the resolution of the sleep is fine enough. (If you can sleep in multiples of 50ms and the timing information is much finer grained, it may not gain you anything; but in a software implementation on unknown hardware there's not much else you can do); this is the way IV is intended to be used, and avoids correlation between messages. Although I'd use base-64 rather than base-16 for converting the messages back to strings. Or character encoding "ISO-8859-1".

Comment: I've added the random sleep to the code now. Is it implemented in a correct way? I thought maybe it doesn't improve anything at all, as CPU load will decrease in the sleep phase and make the duration of sleep obvious. Is this so? And why would you use base-64 instead of hex? Just because it produces shorter strings?

Comment: True, there's still power analysis, but that requires fairly direct access to the device whereas timing attacks don't always. Yes, the base-64 is just to produce shorter strings.

Comment: I've replaced the hex format by base 64 now (I hope I did it right). Is there any (stupid) mistake left in the code now? And when creating the PBEKeySpec, is reading the bytes from the salt enough? Or should I convert it to base 64 first, as well? Same with the password which is converted to a char array.

Answer (score 2):

Two more points:

1. No separator between iv and cipher text.

From `Base64`'s name, you can derive that its base is 64, ie `2**6`, so for your iv length(16 * 8) can't be divided with no reminder, so `encodeToString()` will add padding to you iv. To split two parts of base64 of iv and cipher text conveniently, you may add a separator char larger than 63(`]`, for example) and not special char of regex(for in java `split()` receive a regex string) so that you can easily split them.

2. Use sub-string to get iv.

As upper item has explained, I can't get why you use `2 * IV_LENGTH` to get iv which is wrong. For example, use a iv of 16 bytes, which is 128 bits and `encodingToString()` change it to 24 bytes(128 / 6 = 22 + 2 paddings, for reasons see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)). So it is obvious not `2 * IV_LENGTH`. Try to change to split, see details at item one.